# jQuery selector does not return disabled elements

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a list of checkbox in ASP.NET GridView. At server side I am setting checked property to true and  disabling a few of them. Now when I use following selector, it does not return chekcbox which were disabled but checked.

```
var $checkedCheckboxList = $('form input:checkbox[ID*="_chkItems"]:checked:enabled');
```

What needs to be added in this selector to get checked checkbox which can be disabled also?

Comment: ..and what do you think the `:enabled` part of that selector does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just drop `:enabled` from the selector. It filters out `:disabled` elements.